# Constructing The Cayley Graph and quasi-isometry to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

If we have a group $G$ defined by: $G=\langle a,b\mid b^2=1\rangle$ then I first need to construct the cayley graph of this, now I think that this is going to look like the "telephone pole" metric space (the cayley graph of the group $F(a,b)$) but vertical it will always stop after one application of $b$

I now want to show that this is quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{Z}$. Can I just do this by mapping each vertex $ab^iab^j\cdots$ to $i+j$ in the graph of $\mathbb{Z}$ and sending $b$ to 0?

Comment: Hm, I've never heard of a "telephone pole metric space" and I can't seem to find what it refers to on Google either. I've seen pictures of the Cayley graph of a free group on two generators (like at [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cayley_graph_of_F2.svg) but I'm not sure if telephone poles describe that particular picture. Could you tell me about this allusion you're making? Thanks

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry that is what my lecturer called it so I thought it was pretty standard. The image you posted is what I was referring to, I have no idea why it is called the telephone pole. Am I thinking of the cayley graph of my $G$ in the correct way- as the same as that graph but if we let $b$ be the vertical then it only ever goes up $1$ and then loops back down?

Comment: I know that this really resembles a picture of a [fractal antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_Antenna). These are used in some (all?) modern cellphones. Could this be what the person actually meant?

Comment: Could be I have no idea, they just called it "the telephone pole metric space" in my lectures. Do you have any thoughts on my reasoning?

Comment: My working theory is that they mean "(fractal) phone antenna" but maybe English is not their first language and the expression got garbled. You will probably let me know my speculation is totally wrong, but that's the best idea I have on the subject :) Oh, another theory is that they're thinking of a totally different picture that looks more like a telephone pole.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes but my reasoning about the Cayley graph of $G=\langle a,b|b^2=1\rangle$? will it look like the image that you posted but things only go one high?

Comment: Oh sure, maybe with the constraint it looks like a pole, the $b$ direction being limited as much as possible. I don't use Cayley graphs though, so you'd have to convince yourself. This subject is outside of my ken: I don't even know how this relates to hyperbolic geometry or topology.

Comment: @rschwieb Ok cool, thanks for the help anyway. My lecturer was American so I think english is her first language. I could always email and ask why she called it the telephone pole! :)

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false as written.

$G = \langle a, b \mid b^2 = 1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}_2$. This group is a free product $A \ast_C B$, where $\mid A/C \mid \geq 3$ and $\mid B/C \mid \geq 2$. ($A=\mathbb{Z}, B=\mathbb{Z}_2, C=\{1\}$). By Stalling's Theorem, this group has infinitely many ends. But $\mathbb{Z}$ has 2 ends. Since ends are a quasi-isometry invariant, G cannot be quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{Z}$.

HOWEVER, what you might have meant is that the abelian group $H = \langle a, b \mid [a,b] = b^2 = 1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{Z}$ as it has a finite index cyclic subgroup. Its Cayley graph with respect to the standard generating set is a ladder and also easy to construct.